# Spark map and broadcast together issue in program

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to join two dataset. Below are two dataset .

```
1/2/2009 6:17,iphone,800,Mastercard,carolina
1/2/2009 4:53,cloth,200,Visa,Betina
1/2/2009 13:08,cloth,100,Mastercard,Federica e Andrea
1/3/2009 14:44,blender,160,Visa,Gouya
1/4/2009 12:56,samsung,3600,Visa,Gerd W 
1/4/2009 13:19,htc,1200,Visa,LAURENCE
1/4/2009 20:11,iphone,999,Mastercard,Fleur
1/2/2009 20:09,tmobile,81,Mastercard,adam
1/4/2009 13:17,iphone,400,Cash,Renee Elisabeth
```

similarly other dataset is :

```
Mastercard,MS
Visa,VS
```

I want to join two data set and get output like below:

```
(htc,VS)
(iphone,MS)
(iphone,NULL)
```

Below is what My approach :

```
  def mapCard(cardname:String):String={
    if(cardname.isEmpty()){
      return "NONE"     
    }
    else
      return cardname
  }
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("bc.txt")
    val keymap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
    for (line <- source.getLines) {
      val Array(country, capital) = line.split(",").map { _.trim() }
      keymap += country -> capital
    }

    println(keymap)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("AAA")
    val sparkcontext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val countriesCache = sparkcontext.broadcast(keymap)

    val file = sparkcontext.textFile("salesdata.csv")

    val a = file.map { line => line.split(",") }
                .map { line => {                        
                              var columns = line(3)                                           
                              if(countriesCache.value.contains(columns) )
                                {
                                columns.map { x => ( line(1),countriesCache.value(columns) ) }
                              }                                
                              else 
                                 columns.map { x => (line(1),"NULL") }

                               }
                     }
    a.foreach(x=> println(x.mkString(",")))
  }}
```

This doesnot give me my output.Please suggest me the issue here. Instead it gives like below .

> htc,VS),(htc,VS),(htc,VS),(htc,VS)
>
> > (iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS),(iphone,MS)
> >     (cloth,VS),(cloth,VS),(cloth,VS),(cloth,VS)

Comment: Why don't you just join the datasets?

Comment: I am new to spark and trying to address same problem different way.Can you please suggest the other way.The solution you have given workd. I will accept your answer.Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to problem is that you iterate over the characters of your sing in these lines:

```
columns.map { x => ( line(1),countriesCache.value(columns) ) }
```

and

```
columns.map { x => (line(1),"NULL") }
```

just use

```
( line(1),countriesCache.value(columns) )
```

and

```
(line(1),"NULL")
```

Comment: This worked. Without map function also can we map like this.This was new for me.Thanks